# Partial view html code is not rendered

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, hidden-field

Can anyone tell why the hidden value html is not rendered ? The debugger steps into the conditional, but hidden field is not on the page.

```
<% if (ViewData[Constants.ViewDataKeyandValues.Page]!= null)  
{%>
<input type="hidden" name="Language" value="English" />
<%} %>
```

The project is MVC 2. Thank you!

Comment: Just in case, to be absolutely clear, you mean it's not in the HTML source right? `<input type="hidden">` will of course not be visible by default. I hate to ask for this clarification, but sometimes you never know...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what you may try: remove the `if` condition and let the hidden field unconditional:

```
<input type="hidden" name="Language" value="English" />
```

Now there are 3 possibilities:

1. The hidden is rendered => you haven't set a value in `ViewData[Constants.ViewDataKeyandValues.Page]` inside your controller action. So set a value and you should be fine.
2. The hidden is not rendered => you have a bigger problem with some other part of your code that you haven't shown
3. By *rendered* you mean be part of the HTML source when you view the page but this view was included as part of an AJAX request so the hidden field is correctly injected into the DOM, it's just that you don't see it in the source. Inspect your DOM tree with tools like FireBug and you're gonna see it.

Comment: @Wesley, It can also be that this is a partial view that he is just invoking but not returning correctly to be displayed.

Comment: You got it in possibility 3! Thanks!